# how to make 3 related combos with jquery ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, combobox

OK this is  what i have so far 
1st page gets the data and populate 1st combobox, no problem here,
Then the users select a value from combo1 and (with ajax) a 2nd combobox is created with the filtred data. OK here too!
the problem is that i need that with the combo2.change property, it triggers another ajax request to display final data. 
My problem is that i am not familiar with this enough to create the last request...i can´t understand how to do it...

This is my code on index.php that loads the 2nd combo correctly after processing data in call21.php...at this point i have no scripting in call21.php just the database code to get the needed values, sending it back throw ajax to the div in the index.php page and create the combobox.
(with classe=drop2)...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#wait").css("display","block");
    });

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display","none");
});

$(".drop1").change(function(){
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'user='+ id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "call21.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $(".tab2").html(html);
            $(".tab1").text(id);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

My question is where must i put code to make the 2nd ajax call ??? index.php or call21.php???
can you guys give me a hand with that code?

I have more than 100H of google in this question but my knowledges of this are just too short to find a solution on my own...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic sample

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo for 3 Ajax Form</title>
    <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){

        $(".select:not(:first)").hide();//Hide All Expect First
        //fill up first
            $.get("index.php?select=1",function(data){
                $("#first").html(data);
            }); //
        //
        $("#first").change(function(){
            $.get("index.php?select=2&value="+$("#first").val(),function(data){
                $("#second").html(data);
            });
            $("#second").show();
        });
        $("#second").change(function(){
            $.get("index.php?select=3&value="+$("#second").val(),function(data){
                $("#third").html(data);
            });
            $("#third").show();

        });

    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="select" id="first"></select>
    <select class="select" id="second"></select>
    <select class="select" id="third"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

and index.php

```
<?php 

    $list_for_first = array("a" , "b" , "c");
    $list_for_second = array(array("aa","aa") , array("bb","bb") , array("cc","cc"));
    $list_for_third = array(array("aaa","aaa","aaa") , array("bbb","bbb","bbb") , array("ccc","ccc","ccc"));

    switch ($_GET['select']) {
        case 1:
            foreach ($list_for_first as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            $selected = $_GET['value'];

            foreach ($list_for_second[$selected] as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            $selected = $_GET['value'];

            foreach ($list_for_third[$selected] as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
            }
            break;

    }
?>
```

There are 3 of array for the each select. Then, if change first or second index.php return 'options' by selected option value. The value show the index($key in this code) of the child array. For example, when "b" selected from first one the query string can be like 'index.php?selected=2&value=1' . On the other hand, when "cc" selected from second one the query string should be 'index.php?selected=3&value=2' and index.php returns third child of list_for_third array. Have nice day.